# How to handle empty response in Spring RestTemplate

Tags: spring, rest, jackson, resttemplate

My Authorization service returs a http 204 on success and a http 401 on failure but no responseBody. I'm not able to consume this with the RestTemplate client. It fails attempting to serialize the response. The error from Jackson suggest that i turn on FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS in the serializer, but how do set this in restTemplate

**The client consuming the rest api**

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n ============API REQUEST INTERCEPTOR=============== \n\n\n\n\n");

    if(StringUtils.isBlank(request.getHeader(AuthenticationKeys.AUTHENTICATIONTOKEN.name().toLowerCase()))){
        //TODO AUTHORIZE TOKEN
        ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticateResponse = restTemplate.getForEntity(authenticateUrl, AuthenticationResponse.class);
        if(authenticateResponse.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()){
            //TODO SET THE TOKEN IN THE CONTEXT
            return true;
        }else{
            //TODO DO SOME ERROR HANDLING
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = new AuthorizationRequest();
        authorizationRequest.setToken("TESTNG");
        ResponseEntity<Object> authorizationResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity(authorizeUrl, request, Object.class);
        if(authorizationResponse.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()){
            return true;
        }else{
            //TODO DO SOME ERROR HANDLING
            if(authorizationResponse.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)){
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Oops! access to this API is not authorized to you.");
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**The rest service**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/authorize", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    void authorize(@RequestBody @Valid AuthorizationRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        if(request.getToken().equals("TESTING")){
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
        }else{
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }
}
```

**The exception**

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest["request"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["inputStream"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:26) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:129) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2238) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 52 more
```

**The Attempted Fix**

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
        for(HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters){
            if(converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter){
                ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter).getObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
            }
        }
```

**The next error**

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: getInputStream() has already been called for this request (through reference chain: org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest["request"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["reader"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: getInputStream() has already been called for this request (through reference chain: org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest["request"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["reader"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:238) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:777) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:566) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:529) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:356) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at mordeth.orchestration.interceptor.ApiRequestInterceptor.preHandle(ApiRequestInterceptor.java:120) ~[ApiRequestInterceptor.class:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:134) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at mordeth.orchestration.controller.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:21) [CorsFilter.class:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [shiro-web-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [shiro-web-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:380) [shiro-core-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:67) [log4j-web-2.0.jar:2.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: getInputStream() has already been called for this request (through reference chain: org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest["request"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["reader"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:210) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:177) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:190) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:671) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:129) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2238) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getInputStream() has already been called for this request
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getReader(Request.java:1239) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getReader(RequestFacade.java:505) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.57]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:536) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:663) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:129) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2238) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: What is your spring version?

Comment: Hi, my spring version is 4.1.4.RELEASE and jackson impl is fasterxml version 2.5.0

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use String instead of AuthenticationResponse. If you get an empty response, the String value will be empty.

```
ResponseEntity<String> authenticateResponse = restTemplate.getForEntity(authenticateUrl, String.class);
```

UPDATE: 
Check this [link](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8572). I think this will fix your issue.

```
ResponseEntity<Void> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(authenticateUrl,Void.class);
Void body = response.getBody();
```

Comment: Thanks, Hareesh. I was rather hoping restTemplate would have an elegant way of handling 204 No Content or for that matter any other http code where rest services can communicate with their client just via http codes and not having to have any payload

Comment: btw, this fails, i'd need to have the rest service have a return type(String) instead of void

Comment: in retrospect, Void seems to be the most elegant way to handle no body response